# How can i query a Primary key objects in django 2 template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

after querying my database, my template doesn't display anything. Please find attached my model, url, templates

MODEL

```
   class ScrumyUser(models.Model):
   userRole = (
       ('O', 'Owner'),
       ('A', 'Admin'),
       ('Q', 'Quality Analyst'),
       ('D', 'Developer'),
   )
   fullname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
   role = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=userRole)



class GoalStatus(models.Model):
   goalStatus = (
       ('P', 'Pending'),
       ('V', 'Verified'),
       ('D', 'Done'),
   )
   status = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=goalStatus)


class ScrumyGoals(models.Model):
   goalType = (
       ('WG', 'Weekly Goal'),
       ('DT', 'Daily Task'),
   )

   user_id = models.ForeignKey(ScrumyUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   status_id = models.ForeignKey(GoalStatus, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   goal_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=goalType)
   goal_description = models.TextField()
   date_created = models.DateTimeField('dateCreated')
   date_updated = models.DateTimeField(null=True, blank=True)
```

VIEWS

```
from django.views import generic
from .models import ScrumyGoals, ScrumyUser, GoalStatus


class IndexView(generic.ListView):
    template_name = 'greyscrumy/index.html'
    context_object_name = 'goals'


    def get_queryset(self):

        return ScrumyGoals.objects.all()
```

TEMPLATE INDEX

THIS TEMPLATE DOESN'T DISPLAY ANY DATA ON THE BROWSER

```
{% if goals %} 
   <h1>{{ object_list.fullname }}</h1> 
   <ul>
   {% for goal in goals.scrumygoals_set.all %}
        <li><a href="{% url 'greyscrumy:index' goal.id %}">{{ goal.goal_type }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% else %}
    <p>No goals are available.</p>
{% endif %}
```

THE SECOND DISPLAYS BUT I DON'T KNOW HOW TO ACCESS SCRUMYUSER AND GOALSTATUS

PLEASE I WOULD REALLY LOVE TO UNDERSTAND THIS, I HAVE MADE SEARCHES ON GOOGLE SINCE YESTERDAY AND COULDN'T FIND ANYTHING

```
{% for goal in goals %}

    {% for innergoal in goals %}
        {{ innergoal.id }} {{ innergoal.goal_description }}
    {% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
{% for goal in goals %}
    <h1>{{ goal.user_id.fullname }}</h1>
    <p>{{ goal.goal_type }}</p>
    <p>{{ goal.goal_description }}</p>
    <p>{{ goal.date_created }}</p>
    <p>{{ goal.date_updated }}</p>
    <p>{{ goal.user_id.role }}</p>
    <p>{{ goal.status_id.status }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```